# Order Query by Timestamp and Name from two Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

Note: I am a little new to SQL Server, so this should be an easy question, and I apologize for mistakes in formatting this question.

This is SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have two tables.

- Table 1: `DATA` has key `ID` and columns `PROD_ID, COLLECT_TS`
- Table 2: `PRODUCT` has key `PROD_ID` and column `PROD_NAME`

I want my query to list every `PROD_NAME` by the latest `COLLECT_TS`

Here is what I have thus far:

```
SELECT MAX(COLLECT_TS), PROD_ID
FROM dbo.SG_DATA
GROUP by PROD_ID
```

This successfully returns all the latest `COLLECT_TS` with a `PROD_ID`, but the `PROD_ID` is just a number and doesn't mean anything to the user.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select max(p.prod_name) as prod_name, max(d.collect_ts) as collect_ts
From product p
Join data d -- left join if you want products with no data
    On d.prod_id = p.prod_id
Group by p.prod_id
```

The idea is to join products and data so we get one row for each data entry with the extra information from products attached. Then we group by product id and take the max collect ts from each group. We also take the max name, but that's ok because name will be constant across the group, so we just need some aggregation to select a single value.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much. I knew it was something fairly simple, just needed the right formatting. Thanks again to all that helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables then order by the COLLECT_TS column:

```
Select TB2.PROD_NAME , TB1.COLLECT_TS  From [Table_1] as TB1
Join [Table_2] as TB2 on TB1.PROD_ID = TB2.TB1.PROD_ID 
Order by TB1.COLLECT_TS desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(COLLECT_TS), MAX(PROD_NAME)
FROM dbo.SG_DATA a
inner join dbo.PRODUCT b on a.prod_id = b.prod_id
GROUP by PROD_ID
```